# How to combine 4 commands into 1 in terminal while they are connected logically

Tags: command-line, grep

Can someone help me? I have a **homework** from my university. And I have to put these 4 commands into 1:

```
grep - r - l 'TODO'
ln - s test         --- (It`s the name of file that I get after first command) softlink
grep -v -r -l 'TODO'
chmod 0644 lab      --- (It`s the name of file that I get after previous command)
```

I tried to google this question, but all I get was some stuff with `;` and `&`. But as I understood, it doesn't work in a proper way cause this commands are connected logically (I get the name of the file with which I have to work only after `grep`).

Comment: to filter output using grep you can type e.g `ls -la | grep 'myfile.txt'`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? It appears you are trying to search for a file with "TODO" in the file, then symlink that file to a file called "softlink". And finally change the permissions? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe '|' to use the output of the first command as the input for the second command like this:

```
# <first command> | <second command> ...
```

Comment: This is only really helpful when `<first command>` produces standard output, and `<second command>` consumes standard input (I don't think that's the case for `ln` or `chmod` for example: both need filename *arguments*)

Comment: @streeldriver why not ? If it is hard to handle the heavy output he can use a python command line `python -c ....` to handle it... i think...

Comment: If you did want to use a pipe, the simplest way would be to use `xargs` to turn `stdin` into an argument list